# Preventing user from typing text into a text box but allowing paste keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there was a way to disable all key-down events (such as typing text) while the text box element is selected/has focus but still allow the ctrl+v paste shortcut to be used. In other words I'd like to make it so the only way a user can enter any text into the box is by pasting it (either by using the context menu or by the ctrl+v).

Comment: onkeydown="return false;"

Comment: sorry, asked the question prematurely...I had a check on the return false; for the keydown event whether or not the ctrl key is pressed as well but had a typo! Sorry for the waste of time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code, deactivate keydown, but keep Ctrl+v working.

http://jsfiddle.net/70h3zron/

```
var ctrlActive = false;

$('#idtext').keydown(function(e) {
    if(ctrlActive)
    {
        if(event.which == 86) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(event.which == 17) 
            ctrlActive = true;
        else
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});


$('#idtext').keyup(function(e) {
    if(event.which == 17) {
        ctrlActive = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! I tried something similar but thought it wasn't working because of a mistake in my code, which I didn't spot and assumed I was going about it wrong!

Comment: Don't worry, I read your updated but I already did the code. does your code work fine?

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple solution:

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox" />


$(document).ready(function () {
    var ctrlKey = 17
    var vKey = 86
    $("#txtbox").keydown(function (e) {
        if (!(e.ctrlKey && e.which == vkey)) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m8opf1ju/2/)**

Comment: neat solution. Didn't you could check values like that in keydown events arg

Comment: yes it can be checked. Do you want to check it on `keydown` of whole document?

Comment: apparently there is no need. I tried your code, and it work even if you press ctrl outside the textbox, select the textbox keeping the ctrl pressed and then pressing 'v'. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in jQuery,

```
$('#yourTextElementId').keypress(function(){
    return false;
)};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/9hnkd55g/2/)